# Probability of B intersect A Complement when A is a subset of B

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider two events A and B such that

$P(A) = \frac 13\\P(B) = \frac 12$

Determine the value of $P(B \cap A^c)$ for
the following condition:

$A \subset B$

Comment: Did you draw a Venn diagram?

Comment: I have to explain the answer can't use Venn diagram

Comment: @Newton But maybe using a Venn diagram will help you see what the answer is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$ 
B = (B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^c)
$$
and, since these are disjoint,
$$
\mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}(B \cap A) + \mathbb{P}(B \cap A^c)
$$